# How to use event GA4 measure ecommerce with Nextjs13?

Tags: javascript, next.js, google-analytics, e-commerce, google-tag-manager

I trying to use GA4 measure ecommerce with Next Js 13. I want to use Tag Manager, but I don't understand how can I use it. I read this doc:

- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce?client_type=gtm

I understand that I should set items,  and use dataLayer.push.

But how can I set the dynamic items ? Where I put dataLayer event ?

I wat to use add_to_cart event on my button.
I should write something like this ?

```
const add_tp_cart = ({id,name,value,price,discount_price,index,}) => {
  dataLayer.push({ ecommerce: null }) // Clear the previous ecommerce object.
  dataLayer.push({
    event: 'add_to_cart',
    ecommerce: {
      currency: 'EUR',
      value: value,
      items: [
        {
          item_id: id,
          item_name: name,
          discount: discount_price,
          index: index,
          price: price,
          quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
    },
  })
}
```

Anyone could help me to undestand ?